# Reference request for an explicit description of the group of deck transformations acting on the universal cover of a Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Sigma_g$ be a geuns $g$ Riemann surface with $g \geq 2$. 
It can be thought of  in the following way: 
it is the quotient space 
$$\mathbb{H}/\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$$ where an element of $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ can be thought of as a biholomorphic map  $~f: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ 
and $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane with the Hyperbolic metric.

Moreover, for a fixed $\Sigma_g$ there will be different families of maps representing $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$, which will induce distinct complex structures on $\Sigma_g$.

I am looking for a reference where these maps are explicitly written down, for 
$g \geq 2 $.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ The question as stated initially was wrong as has been pointed out. A genus $g$ Riemann surface is the quotient of the Hyperbolic space and not the complex plane.

Comment: @Daniel You are right. I have made the correction to my question.

Comment: I've sketched the necessary steps here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377958/explicit-description-of-the-group-of-deck-transformations-acting-on-the-universa/377992#377992